# .htaccess redirect loop, cant get site to work

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

Hello I got a redirect loop going on with my .htaccess. I have a website at example.example.com and the location of my script is located at example.example.com/index/. When I'm going to example.example.com I just see the folder directory, however I can access my script via example.example.com/index/, I had inserted a .htaccess using 301 forward, however I am getting an endless redirect loop. How can I use php, html or .htaccess to direct when someone types in example.example.com and gets example.example.com/index/? I can't seem to figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add code... or at least try .htaccess before asking questions about it.

Comment: Yes. Show us what's in your `.htaccess` file so we can see where the glitch might be. Also, consider reading [When Not To Use Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index.php**
`<?php header("location: ./index/");?>`

**OR**

**index.html**
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/index/">`

**OR**

put your .htaccess with redirect rule in root folder, and put another .htaccess in `index` folder with: `RewriteEngine off` to stop loop

(in root folder)

Comment: for the php this is what I am getting "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/example/public_html/projects/index.php:6) in /home/example/public_html/projects/index.php on line 6"

Comment: php code needs to be in the first line of the file, with no spaces before

Comment: Excellent answer! I was able to fix the issue by creating a index.html file in root folder with code "<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/index.html">" :)